# Meaning of verb + かなど in article

Tags: grammar, particle-など

I'm about to finish reading this [article](https://www3.nhk.or.jp/news/easy/k10011761001000/k10011761001000.html) and I came across some grammer that I have never seen before in the last sentence. The last sentence is:

> これから、どのくらいとる**かなど**を決める予定です。

What is the bolded part here supposed to mean? I have never seen かなど used before and definitely would not expect it to follow a verb.

My best guess translation:

> After this, the plan is to decide on how much to take or something

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> これから、どのくらいとる**かなど**を決める予定です。

This is simply two separate particles performing their usual separate functions. など means 'things like'.

か is marking the embedded question どのくらいとるか (how much will they catch?). There are loads of posts on embedded questions on this site, but essentially the whole embedded question can act as a noun and can therefore be the object of 決める.

Your translation effort is pretty close. I'd go with something like:

> After this the plan is to decide things like how much to catch.

Note that とる can mean 'catch' when talking about fish.